# CICS transaction not releasing resources when it finishes

Tags: cics

I am trying to find a memory leak in a CICS transaction. The transaction runs a Cobol program which calls a C DLL which does a connect to a socket, a number of mallocs, then disconnects and frees the memory.

This transaction is leaking memory but it also does not free any of the memory when it stops. I have carefully matched all the malloc and frees (as well as getaddrinfo / freeaddrinfo) and I have tested the same cobol program outside of CICS and it does not leak.

What CICS settings will ensure the resources are freed when the transation returns? Also are there any tips to debug the memory leak? What else could it be if it isn't the mallocs? I have noticed the TCPIP getaddrinfo / freeaddrinfo is being logged to SYSTCPT, is this using CICS region space?

Answer (score 1):

[CICS releases storage](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=cics-storage-management-under) allocated by code running under a transaction at Language Environment (LE) enclave termination. If the C DLL does not use LE for its runtime then you are at the mercy of the behavior of whatever runtime is being used by the C DLL.

You mention using sockets.  If the C DLL was not [compiled and linked](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=server-zos-communications-ip-cics-sockets-guide) to use the CICS Sockets Interface then you are at the mercy of the behavior of whatever runtime is being used by the C DLL.

Your CICS Sysprog can modify the LE runtime options dynamically using the [CLER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=descriptions-cler-language-environment-runtime-options) transaction.  The RPTSTG option *may* reveal useful information.

Your CICS Sysprog can start a trace for storage management with the [CETR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=descriptions-cetr-trace-control) transaction.  This *may* reveal useful information.

I say *may* reveal useful information because if your C DLL is not using LE for its runtime it's possible these techniques will not help you.

Comment: The C DLL is compiled with CICS Sockets and it does use LE.

Comment: RPTSTG shows HEAP is set to HEAP(4096,4080,ANYWHERE,KEEP,4096,4080) .

Comment: @MichaelTaylor ask your CICS SYSPROG to run and interpret a trace for you.

Comment: So after much testing I think it is this bug http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1PK98008 - our connect code uses getaddrinfo() and freeaddrinfo is not freeing it due to a bug!

Comment: It does appear to be that bug - so the problem was not in the code but the CICS TCPIP library.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor I'm glad you found it.

Comment: thanks for your help. CLER in particular was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that there is a bug in the CICS TCPIP library on our version of z/OS and CICS. The module EZACIC17 that must be linked to your code has a bug where getaddrinfo() incorrectly marks the structures it allocates. When you call freeaddrinfo() this memory is not released and, eventually, the CICS region runs out of storage. Our development system is z/OS 1.8 and CICS is V3.1 and there is no fix for that version so we will need to upgrade.

All memory in the C program allocated with malloc() will be released when released with free(). However any resources not explicitly released are not returned when the application / transaction finishes. Out application uses C DLLs which appear to stay in memory. When you run the application again the total amount of memory used by CICS stays constant. SO as long as their is no memory leak in our code CICS memory usage does not increase.